# What is the difference between createTable(...).createTable(...) and createTable(...).then(...) in knex.js?

Tags: javascript, knex.js

I am using knex.js to connect to a MySQL database. I want to create a couple of tables. So far, I have seen two styles. One of them chains the use of `createTable`like so,

```
    knex.schema.createTable('foo',function(table){...}).createTable('bar'...)
```

The other style uses the `then` mechanism to do the same thing.

```
    knex.schema.createTable('foo',function(table){...}).then(function() {
        knex.schema.createTable.createTable('bar'...)
```

Are they semantically similar? Can I assume they do the same thing?
Will both of them execute the second clause once the first clause completely finishes?

Comment: It seems odd (although not impossible) that `createTable` would return an object that works like a "schema" and a "promise".. and *both* forms work?

Comment: the promise is executed asynchronously

Comment: @user28640 I remember seeing `createTable(...).createTable(...` somewhere on SO. Hopefully, I didn't dream it up...

Comment: @Sekai Ah. So the first form is executed synchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a comment should be enough as answer, but

```
then
```

in Javascript returns a promise which is executed asynchronously, while the other method is executed synchronously and your javascript won't get to the next line until the line is executed.